# howdo i get relative path using php function

Tags: php, split, compare, preg-match, trim

I am have a string having url

```
   /abc/xyz/index.php/pqr/wer
```

I want the result as path after **index.php***

i.e;

```
   pqr/wer
```

to be stored in a variable

I did try with

```
  Preg_match,trim,split,substring
```

split splits it but then how do i get path after index.php

what if i have

```
   $url =/abc/xyz/index.php
```

it return **index.php**

Comment: Where do you get the url from? is it from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

Comment: then what you are searching for is called path-info and stored in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Comment: @baerbjoern i get the url from my mvc framework function thanks  you i got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
print str_replace('index.php/','',strstr ( $url , 'index.php'));
```

Comment: can you please explain  how it works?thanks this works... direct print prq/wer and no array :)

Comment: @user3419342 Basically strstr($haystack,$needle) returns substring from haystack starting with needle. That substring contains extra 'index.php/' which is being removed by using str_replace

Comment: @user3419342 just the answer accepted, no upvotes? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` to get the string following `index.php`:

```
preg_match( '/index.php\/(.*)/i', '/abc/xyz/index.php/pqr/wer', $arMatches );

print_r( $arMatches );
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => index.php/pqr/wer [1] => pqr/wer )
```

`$arMatches[1]` is what you want.

Comment: works thanks:) in array format.... but then following gives direct answer print str_replace('index.php/','',strstr ( $url , 'index.php'));